# Why does my pdf image cause a bug only after printing the document?

Tags: printing, debugging, bugs

So I have a page that looks normal on screen.
It looks like this on the screen;

[image: screenshot of page]

Near the top of that page a figure is displayed. This figure is a pdf, created in inkscape.
In the `.tex` the figure placement looks like;

```tex
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{compressed_event_parts}
        \caption{Symbolic depiction of the physics processes occurring in an event.
                 The hard event is where new physics might be found,
                 and the end points of the shower are the detectable remnants of this.
                 Three types of noise are depicted; MPI, pileup, and ISR.
             }\label{fig:event_parts}
    \end{figure}
```

Nothing unusual about the figure environment. There are plenty of other figures in the same document that have no issues.

However, if I print it out, the figure, and the whole page, goes bonkers;

[image: physical page after printing]

Printing just the figure on its own works fine. Other parts of the document work fine. If I print to pdf, or print preview, there is nothing wrong.

It seems likely that the issue is somehow related to my printer's drivers. But given that my printer's drivers have never done this before, there must be something anomalous about the document too?

Now I recognise, that a simple and expedient solution would be to convert the problem figure to a `.jpg`. But I went to some lengths to produce it as a vector graphic, I'd like it to stay as a vector graphic. For the problem image, plus a minimum broken example, please see [this repository](https://github.com/HenryDayHall/problem_image).

Firstly, what is causing this?

Secondly, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: slightly odd, nt surprising that latex itself doesn't cpmplain it doesn't really look at the internals, but a bit surprising it works on screen and not in print. You could use pdf2ps and ps2pdf  (ie ghostscript) to convert  the file to PS and back to PDF, that can sometimes normalize dodgy pdf or at least give coherent warnings if it finds something wrong. oh no that rasterises it to a bitmap

Comment: I would take a closer look at the image, perhaps with a graphics editor.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't know what I would be looking for, on it's own the image prints fine. It's in the repository linked if you have an idea?

Comment: If you crop an image, the entire image will be stored in the PDF, not just the visible portion.  OTOH, I have no idea how to access any invisible parts.  Neither GIMP not Acrobat revealed anything.  OTOH, why did you use [compressed_event_parts] instead of [event_parts]?

Comment: @JohnKormylo oh, yeah sorry I was messing around with compressing the pdf, to see if the compression software would get rid of the issue. It didn't work. Your comments about invisible sections give me something to try though - I think inkscape has a function to 'clean up' invisible elements, so I will give that a go.

Comment: Can't reproduce; but then the printer I tested on is A4 black and white while your example document isn't A4 so I have to set the geometry to fit; that *might* be the cause)